# Bean binding not working in ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a flow defining a helper that submits correctly the data

```
<var name="contactForm" class="my.package.bean.ContactFormHelper"/>
```

To get some data based on user input I use in the view an ajax call on the binded attribute `String id` in this way:

```
<h:panelGroup >
    <p:outputLabel for="id" value="ID" />
    <p:inputText id="id" required="true" value="#{contactForm.id}" label="ID">
        <f:ajax 
            event="change" 
            listener="#{contactController.identifyCustomer(contactForm)}" 
            render="anotherPanel" 
        />
        <p:clientValidator/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:message for="id" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

But when `identifyCustomer` is executed only the field where ajax is placed (`String id`) is updated. The rest of fields are filled with default values.

**LOG TRACE**

> [21/11/16 17:10:12:508 CET] 0000007a SystemOut     O DEBUG [WebContainer : 0 : 8610ff45-f4c5-4faf-a370-efa36701bc01] - **ContactForm[name=, surnames= , nif=46713535Y]**

Some idea of why is this happening?

Comment: There is only one field in the example... [mcve] please (and did you try a `p:ajax`?)

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes  answers your question I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution with `process` using `@this` and fields separated by commas:

```
<p:ajax 
    event="change" 
    listener="#contactController.identifyCustomer(contactForm)}"
    <!-- add process with the fields to bind -->
    process="@this name,surname1,surname2"
    update="newCustomerPanel" 
/>
```

Hope it help to others.